# How to make QTextToSpeech say "%n error(s)" correctly in different languages?

Tags: qt, internationalization, text-to-speech

I'm using the Qt Translator's handling of the diversity of plural cases in different languages. In particular, in Russian there are singular, dual and plural cases (that's what Qt Linguist calls them), and I can use

```
tr("%n error(s)", "", errorCount)
```

to get the correct translation of e.g.

```
1 error  → 1 ошибка
3 errors → 3 ошибки
6 errors → 6 ошибок
```

That's fine when I want to present the text as *text* — e.g. in a message box. But if I try making `QTextToSpeech` pronounce this (I tried it by pasting the text into Qt's `hello_speak` example), I get bad results, because e.g. "1 error" is pronounced as "один ошибка" instead of "одна ошибка" (incorrect agreement by gender: *ошибка* is feminine, *одна* is feminine, but *один* is masculine).

I suppose it's not currently possible for `QTextToSpeech` engines to find out that the number should somehow agree with several words following or preceding it, so a solution should involve transformation of the textual form to something a speech engine could unambiguously pronounce correctly (i.e. feed "one error" instead of "1 error" to `QTextToSpeech`). But I'd like to fix it in some generic way, so that I didn't have to manually create a "number-to-text" converter for each target language.

How can I fix this (with Qt facilities, if possible)?

Comment: Can you translate `1 error` as `одна ошибка`? I.e. use words for numbers, instead of using [0-9] characters.

Comment: @vahancho yes, this should be done. Just keep in mind that numbers are parameters, not hard coded into the strings. So simple translation of `"1 error"` literal is far from being enough.

Comment: Well, you might rephrase the message like: `количество ошибок 1`. This will be universal and grammatically correct for all cases, as far as I know Russian language.

Comment: @vahancho it won't, unfortunately: "количество ошибок: одна/две/три" — the numerals still need to be in the correct gender. Compare with warnings: "количество предупреждений: одно/два/три".